# Akka library import for sbt project using Java not recognized in IntelliJ I

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dependencies, sbt, akka

I imported a sbt project into intelliJ (using Java language for the project). I have the associated dependencies in the build.sbt file for akka. For some reason, my Akka library is not being recognized by the IDE. I can compile the example code and run it. Does anyone know how I can trouble shoot or resolve this?

Here is the code in my build.sbt file-

```
val scala3Version = "3.2.2"
lazy val akkaVersion = "2.8.0"
lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "akkademo1",
    version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
    fork := true,
    connectInput in run := true, // This is required for console input to work!

    // This is required as a workaround for https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/14846
    compileOrder := CompileOrder.JavaThenScala,
    scalaVersion := scala3Version,
    javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "20", "-target", "20", "--enable-preview"),
    javaOptions ++= Seq("--enable-preview"),

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-typed" % akkaVersion,
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % akkaVersion,
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.4.6",
      "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor-testkit-typed" % akkaVersion % Test,
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.12" % Test,
)
  )
```

[image]

I tried to invalidate cache but didnt work. I tried to reimport but that didnt work either.

Comment: I just created a `new sbt project` in my Intellij (latest version), copy pasted your `build.sbt` and copy pasted the `hello world` example from [Introduction to Actors](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/actors.html). Everything looks fine and I was able to execute it without any issue. Are those libraries listed in the `project explorer` tab in the `External Libraries` section? Maybe you can check the `project structure` menu what libraries are being imported